# Zombie vs Defunct processes?

Tags: linux, process, zombie-process

Is there a difference between zombie and defunct processes? I have found the wikipedia article where it is written that this two are the same. In that case why it is needed to have 2 different terms for the same process:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process

Comment: Only having 2 terms for something is doing pretty good relative to the rest of the computer business.  Everything in a database has 5+ names, often reusing the same words for different parts.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/201303/what-is-a-defunct-process-and-why-doesnt-it-get-killed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Linux "defunct" and "zombie" processes are the same.

From `man ps`:

> Processes marked `<defunct>` are dead processes (so-called "zombies") that remain because their parent has not destroyed them properly. These processes will be destroyed by init(8) if the parent process exits.

```
PROCESS STATE CODES
    Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state of a process:
    D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
    R    running or runnable (on run queue)
    S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
    T    stopped by job control signal
    t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
    W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
    X    dead (should never be seen)
    Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent
```

Answer (score 2):

As Achal said defunct was added by [ps](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/v3.3.15/proc/escape.c#L236). Strictly speaking, they are not the same thing.

For example, only tid 10941 was a zombie in the following table. 
The other threads were in stat D instead of Z.

```
$ grep prometheus foo/bar/sos_commands/process/ps_-elfL
4 Z root      10941  10920  10941  0    6  80   0 -      0 exit   Mar14 ?  00:11:41 [prometheus] <defunct>
1 D root      10941  10920  11010  0    6  80   0 - 621811 wait_o Mar14 ?  00:11:08 [prometheus] <defunct>
1 D root      10941  10920  11025  0    6  80   0 - 621811 wait_o Mar14 ?  00:08:13 [prometheus] <defunct>
1 D root      10941  10920  11057  0    6  80   0 - 621811 wait_o Mar14 ?  00:11:12 [prometheus] <defunct>
1 D root      10941  10920  11060  0    6  80   0 - 621811 wait_o Mar14 ?  00:11:42 [prometheus] <defunct>
1 D root      10941  10920  11298  0    6  80   0 - 621811 wait_o Mar14 ?  00:11:05 [prometheus] <defunct>
```

Comment: Good point. Thank you. So what is the real difference between Z and D?

Comment: Z is dead while D is sleeping.

Comment: man page of ps shows:

`PROCESS STATE CODES`

`D: uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)`
`Z:  defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent`

Answer (score 1):

Both `Zombie` and `defunct` are same. `ZOMBIE` is the one of the `state of the process` while there is no `defunct` state, you can see it from your kernel source code.

```
enum proc_state {
    UNUSED,   /*** processes in initial state **/
    EMBRYO, 
    SLEEPING,
    RUNNABLE, 
    RUNNING, 
    ZOMBIE   /** processes in final state **/
};
```

*Zombie state means where it has exited but has not yet been cleaned up*.

you can open man page of `proc(1)` and see this `/proc/[pid]/stat` Status  information about the process.  This is used by `ps(1)`.